# Upload a file from form in S3 bucket using boto3 and handler is created in lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to upload image , audio files of small size from  form to the S3 using postman for test. I successfully uploaded file in AWS S3 bucket from my application running on my local machine. Following is the part of the code I used for file uploading .

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id =AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,)

async def save_file_static_folder(file, endpoint, user_id):       



 _, ext = os.path.splitext(file.filename)

    raw_file_name = f'{uuid.uuid4().hex}{ext}'
    # Save image file in folder
    if ext.lower() in image_file_extension:


        relative_file_folder =user_id+'/'+endpoint
        
    contents = await file.read()

    try:
        response = s3_client.put_object(Bucket = S3_BUCKET_NAME,Key = (relative_file_folder+'/'+raw_file_name),Body = contents)
        
    except:
        return FileEnum.ERROR_ON_INSERT
```

I called this function from another endpoint and form data (e.g. name, date of birth and other details) are successfully saved in Mongodb database and files are uploaded in S3 bucket.

**This app is using fastapi and files are uploaded in S3 bucket while deploying this app in local machine.**

Same app is delpoyed in AWS lambda and S3 bucket as storage. For handling whole app , following is added in endpoint file.

```
handler = Mangum(app)
```

After deploying app in AWS creating lambda function from root user account of AWS, files didnot get uploaded in S3 bucket.

**If I didnot provide files during form then the AWS API endpoint successfully works. Form data gets stored in MongoDB database (Mongodb atlas) and app works fine hosted using Lambda.**

App deployed using Lambda function works successfully except file uploads in form. FOr local machine, file uploads in S3 get success.

**EDIT**

While tracing in Cloudwatch I got following error

```
exception  An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

I checked AWS Access Key Id and secret key many times and they are correct and root user credentials are kept.

Comment: You won't get good responses to a question that simply says "it doesn't work". You should always include the symptoms of the failure (error messages, return codes, exception information, logging etc.)

Comment: @jarmod I have added my error traces.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "root credentials are kept". The credentials you're providing are incorrect. You're passing an invalid or perhaps malformed (whitespace?) access key. Create an STS client, call [get-caller-identity](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity), and print the results to see. Bigger picture, this is a Lambda function. You shouldn't be providing IAM user credentials; you should be using an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html).

Comment: i mean to say root user 
ACCESS SECRET KEY and ACCESS KEY ID.. I am using IAM role (with attached policies - AmazonS3FullAccess, CloudWatchLogsFullAccess, AwsLambda_FullAcess),  in my lambda function. The same access key works if deployed  on my machine and files are stored on S3 bucket.

Comment: If your Lambda function is configured to run with an IAM role, then your code should not explicitly supply credentials. Simply use: `s3_client = boto3.client('s3')`. You should not be using [root credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html) at all, except in emergencies. They should be MFA-protected and locked away.

Comment: s3_client = boto3.client('s3')  This finally worked

Comment: Glad to see it's working Himal. BTW the typical protocol in this situation is to ask the person who provided you with the answer, albeit in a comment, to write that up as an answer.

Comment: But when I try to open image file from object URL  (by enabling bucket public)  following message is generated.  That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.

Comment: You would typically include `ContentType='image/png'`, or whatever is a relevant content type for your file, when uploading to S3. If there is no explicit content type then I think it defaults to `application/octet-stream` and your browser may not know how to deal with that. You can use curl/wget to download the file to check its contents are correct, or use the awscli to download it.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html
This worked by adding multipart/form-data to the binary media types section in API gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have configured your Lambda function with an execution IAM role, but you are overriding the AWS credentials supplied to the boto3 SDK here:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id =AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,)
```

You don't need to provide credentials explicitly because the boto3 SDK (and all language SDKs) will automatically retrieve credentials dynamically for you. So, ensure that your Lambda function is configured with the correct IAM role, and then change your code as follows:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
```

As an aside, you indicated that you may be using AWS [root credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html). It's generally a best security practice in AWS to not use root credentials. Instead, create IAM roles and IAM users.

> We strongly recommend that you do not use the root user for your everyday tasks, even the administrative ones. Instead, adhere to the best practice of using the root user only to create your first IAM user. Then securely lock away the root user credentials and use them to perform only a few account and service management tasks.